# export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE on windows 7

Tags: python, django, windows-7, python-unittest

I'm trying to run a pyunit unittest that depends on django project imports.

I had to export the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MOCUDLE since it wasn't set so i ran:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=C:/bobbapython/boon/cms.settings
```

Which is the path to the projectroot where the .settings folder is.
I've also tried:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=C:/bobbapython/boon/cms/.settings
```

I also tried with \ instead of / with no success.

I get this error message when trying to run the script via cmd

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manager/tests/test_user_api/generate_testdata.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django import db
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'C:/bobbapython/boon/cms.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

Any suggestions on what i might be doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by instead adding the directory where the settings.py file was to the python path and changing the settings module to "settings". I did this using:

```
path = 'C:\\bobbapython\\boon\\cms\\src\\boon_cms'
sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

once i did this the file ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not a file path. It is a Python module reference.

'C:/bobbapython/boon' should be in your PYTHONPATH, and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should then just be 'cms.settings'.

Comment: tried this, added the path using sys.path.append("C:\\bobbapython\\boon") in the top of the test file and added a print to make sure it was added properly(which it was) and then did a set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=cms.settings. only difference is that it now says: "ImportError: Could not import settings 'cms.settings'"